# type error during component inheritance in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, inheritance

I've encountered an error during inheritance and I don't know how to overcome that, this is a simplified example:

```
// just a class
abstract class AbstractExample<T> {
  public readonly items$ = this.getItems$();
  protected abstract getItems(): Observable<Array<T>>
}

@Component(...)
class Example extends AbstractExample<User> {
  constructor(protected readonly store: Store) { super(); }
  protected getItems() {
    return this.store.select(...);
  }
}
```

so the generated JavaScript code on ES5 target looks similar to that:

```
var Example = /** @class */ (function (_super) {
        __extends(Example, _super);
        function Example(store) {
            var _this = _super.call(this) || this;
            _this.store = store;
        return _this;
    }
    Example.prototype.getItems$ = function () {
        return this.store.select(...);
    };
    return Example;
}(shared_feature_1.AbstractExample));
```

as you may notice the `_super.call` precedes assignation `store` to `this` which results in `TypeError: this.store is undefined` during the `getItems$` method execution

how can I overcome that?

Comment: Same problem as the duplicate, you access the abstract member during base class initialization, the duplicate does so in the constructor, but it's the same idea.

Comment: thanks, so in my case I'm forced to initialize the props in the `ngOnInit` hook.

Comment: Yeah, that should work fine, anywhere after the constructors are done